# While searching a character, I removed the excess \n in a *.txt file and print it. But I don't understand why it print only this

Tags: python-3.x, printing, full-text-search

Edited at 19:19 like I said in a comment

Here is the text file first: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtxgyk9v25p7swt/mbox-short.txt?dl=0
and my code is:

```
xfile = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in xfile:
    # La prochaine ligne est pour enlever les espaces supperflus
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From:') :
        print(line)
```

The output is this:

```
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
From: rjlowe@iupui.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
```

and more.

What I am asking in this. When my program finds what I am looking for, it prints "From ....za". Now I know that there are more characters following za before it reaches the character \n? How my program do to decide to print only "From ....za" and not the others characters?

Thanks in advance for the trouble.
Mario

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the problem is. Do you mean that it doesn't print the `Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008` in the first line for example?

Comment: It's exactly that! Why the program stop there?

Comment: It seems like your program picks up line 38, not 1, when searching for the "From: ". Try replacing it by "From " and it should fix it

Comment: Since French is my first language, I see that the question is ill-written. I will edit it to clarify what I am searching for by my question.

Comment: Like Hacked said: You are printing lines that start with `From:`, not lines just starting with `From`. Remove the `:` to get the other lines, too.